# Can Pydantic model_dump() return exact type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I find 0 other people asking this so I just have to ask:

**Q**: How could I get a typed "dump" from a Pydantic model?

**My context**:

We have `.model_dump()` but its return type hint is `dict[str, Any]`. This is annoying is because I want to write a FastAPI backend with SQLAlchemy ORM and Pydantic models. When creating an ORM model we have only one option (I think) to create an instance, calling constructor with kwargs. Say User is an SQLAlchemy model (declarative base), we create one like:

`User(name="John")`

With a Pydantic model UserCreate we could feed it in like

```
user = UserCreate(name="John")
User(**user.model_dump())
```

Now we cannot get static type checking to make sure our Pydantic UserCreate fields align with SQLAlchemy User model.
So if I add a new field to my SQLAlchemy model like:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase

class BaseDBModel(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(BaseDBModel):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    age: Mapped[int] = mapped_column()
```

and my PydanticModel is

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    name: str
```

There's no way for a static type checker to see that the dict `user.model_dump()` is missing an `age`.

```
user = UserCreate(name="John")
User(**user.model_dump())
```

so it's left to runtime errors to realize you forgot age on UserCreate. I know Tiangolo (creator of FastAPI) has his own ORM (SQLModel) which might fix this, but it's too young to adopt.

SQLAlchemy version 2.0.23
Pydantic version 2.5

Comment: why don"t you add `age` in your pydantic model if it need to be checked ? I assume you work with the your object afterward so you will need to access the `age` attribute

Comment: I could, but let's say I have forgotten that. I have just added age to SQLAlchemy model. Then I have no static type checker showing in my editor that an attribute is missing. We want these checkers to catch errors before runtime. That's why I want a typed dump

Comment: You can check the fields in your test.

Answer (score 1):

No, `model_dump` cannot return an exact type.

However, you don't have to use `model_dump`. Consider providing all the values explicitly instead. This way you won't be able to *forget* a required field.

Either you get an error that `UserCreate` has no attribute defined

```py
user = UserCreate(name="John")

# error: "UserCreate" has no attribute "age" [attr-defined]
User(name=user.name, age=user.age)
```

or that you haven't provided a required attribute

```py
user = UserCreate(name="John")

# error: Missing named argument "age" for "User"
User(name=user.name)
```